# Options for viewing subtitles with itunes movies

Tags: subtitles

I love renting/buying movies from Apple TV, but a lot of them come without subtitles.

Is there a way to view subtitles (even if it's on my computer) while watching a movie?

Some movies I rent but can't even understand half of what they say.  I've found opensubtitles.org but it's full of ads and I'm hesitant to download any malware-infested subtitle player.  Getting the subtitles file is fine, but then what?

Also, as of recent, I thought all movies were supposed to include subtitles.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about home video.  Audio-Video Production is a site for professional production related Audio-Video questions.  You might have better luck on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

If you can have access to video files, then you can easily download subtitles from any website, and then use any video player(media player classic || vlc) to watch movie with subtitle. However not all subtitles can fit to your movie, because of difference of fps, speed of movie, etc. So after some time you might notice, that subtitle speed getting slower or faster. All you have to do, is to name subtitle file with same name as your movie file. For ex.
your movie file: `transformers-blah-blah.mkv`
then your subtitle file should be `transformers-blah-blah.mkv.srt`